# android : How to select multiple Images from gallery and then add into horizontal scrollable Multiple imageView

Tags: android, android-imageview

help me to solve this question in android :

android : How to select multiple Images from gallery and then add into horizontal scroll able Multiple imageView ...!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/yazeed44/MultiImagePicker) library for selecting multiple images

Just call the intent using

```
private void pickImages(){
    final Intent pickIntent = new Intent(this, PickerActivity.class); 
    pickIntent.putExtra(PickerActivity.LIMIT_KEY, 6); // Set a limit , you can skip that if you want no limit

    startActivityForResult(pickIntent, PickerActivity.PICK_REQUEST); //Open gallery
}
```

And in your onActivityResult,

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(resultCode, requestCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PickerActivity.PICK_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //No problemo

        final String[] paths = data.getStringArrayExtra(PickerActivity.PICKED_IMAGES_KEY);//Paths for chosen images (Organized)

        //Do what you want with paths
```

For displaying them horizontally u can use [this](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34) link that shows implementation of horizontal listview using a custom library

in your xml use

```
<com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontialListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ddd"
/>
```

and set adapter using

```
HorizontialListView listview = (HorizontialListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
listview.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```